# Multiple ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath options?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I am binding a collection of objects to a `ComboBox`. What I want to achieve is a combobox that displays two properties of my object. However, I haven't figured out how to make a combobox display multiple `DisplayMemberPaths`. Is this possible?

This is how I'm currently setting up my Binding, and setting the `DisplayMemberPath`:

```
Binding comboBinding = new Binding();
comboBinding.Source = squad_members; //squad_members is the object collection

BindingOperations.SetBinding(Character_ComboBox, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, comboBinding);
Character_ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name"; //
//Character_ComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name" + "Age"; //failed attempt
Character_ComboBox.SelectedValuePath = "Name";
```

Answer (score 13):

First of all you should do the binding in XAML instead of code behind.

You can provide **`ItemTemplate`** and use **`StringFormat`** in **`MultiBinding`** like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                        <Binding Path="Name"/>
                        <Binding Path="Age"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

---

In case you want to do binding still in code behind.

You can ***omit setting DisplayMemberPath altogether by overriding ToString()*** method in your underlying source class. Since, internally ToString() gets called if DisplayMemberPath is not provided.

Say you collection is of type `List<Person>`, so you can override ToString() on Person class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Name + Age;
}
```

With this in place, binding will look like this *(DisplayMemberPath not needed)*

```
Binding comboBinding = new Binding();
comboBinding.Source = squad_members; //squad_members is the object collection

BindingOperations.SetBinding(Character_ComboBox,
                   ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, comboBinding);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an ItemTemplate of your ComboBox,Use many TextBlock, as many columns you need. Something like this,

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<TextBlock Width="50" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
<TextBlock Width="50" Text="{Binding Path=Age}" />
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This is a cleaner solution than the one with the converter

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, you can either have a property that returns what you want, or better, a converter that will do the job for you.

Prop:

```
public int First {get; set;}
public int Second {get; set;}
public int BindToThis {get{return First+Second;}}
```

Converter: See example [In this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

Mainly along the lines:

```
<TextBlock Name="textBox2" DataContext="{StaticResource NameListData}">
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myNameConverter}"
                  ConverterParameter="FormatLastFirst">
      <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
      <Binding Path="LastName"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

and:

```
public class NameConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert( object[] values
                         , Type targetType
                         , object parameter
                         , CultureInfo culture )
    {
        string name;

        switch ((string)parameter)
        {
            case "FormatLastFirst":
                name = values[1] + ", " + values[0];
                break;
            case "FormatNormal":
            default:
                name = values[0] + " " + values[1];
                break;
        }

        return name;
    }

    //  public object[] ConvertBack...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you simply override the ToString method in your class e.g.

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + " " + Age;
    }
```